# Custom validation rule with request class not working laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

Below is my code;

**FruitRequest.php**

```
class FruitRequest extends Request
{

public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|alpha',
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return ['name.required' => response("Name should be mandatory", 404),
        'name.alpha' => response("Name should be contains only letters", 404),
        'image.required' => response("Foto should be mandatory", 404),
        'image.mimes' => response('Foto should be jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg', 404),
        'image.max' => response('Foto size should be blow 2 MB', 404),
    ];
}
```

}

**FruitController.php**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\FruitRequest;

class FruitController extends Controller
{

public function store(FruitRequest $request)
{
    echo $request->input('name');

    //above line gives nothing to me
}

}
```

If I use `extends Request` instead of `extends FruitRequest` then this gives me value which is passed by user in postman. I don't know why this custom Request class not working.I attached screenshot. Please help....

[image]

Comment: it is extends Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest; not Illuminate\Http\Request;

Comment: @AlzafanChristian This is working but I want to know that how can I return a custom response from the controller if validation fails and I got validation message even I both parameter inserting right. can you have idea for this?

Answer (score 0):

long time not using postman, i'm testing with my code

I'm using FormRequest like this:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;

class YourRequest extends FormRequest
{
  //this function called if Validator::make()->fails();
  //here where you can modifying your message
  protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
  {
    //note this only for API, for formData use \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException($validator)
    throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json($validator->errors()->all(), 422));
    //this will get parameter attribute set from FormRequest
    //attributes() along with the error message, 
    //or $validator->errors()->all() to get messages only like my screenshot
    //or modify message with your logic
  }

  public function authorize() { return true; }
  public function rules() { return []; }
  public function attributes() { return []; }
  public function messages() { return []; }
}
```

in controller :

```
use YourRequest;

public function store(YourRequest $req)
{
  return response($req->all())->setStatusCode(200); 
}
```

in your FormRequest replace response(), just text:

```
public function messages()
{
    return ['name.required' => "Name should be mandatory"],
}
```

2nd, validation `alpha` only accepts alphabet, which your name is numeric,
result from my code(i use default validator message which in array of messages) :
[image: postman]

Comment: I inserted both fields correct still validation gives message. I can't echo field

Comment: replace your Request with normal Request from function, so you can dump the input fields

Comment: or use this if you trying to using my code, in failedValidation() dd($validator->errors()->all());

Comment: I dont understand what you are saying. Actually I'm new in laravel. Can you write code in your answer. I want to return custome response like {"code":"404","message":"Name field is empty"}.

Comment: you are not asking for it in your question. my answer edited

Comment: if your request is not ajax, use $errors in your blade to see the message

Comment: Actually I am not working with blade, I am developing the rest API for mobile development. and if I enter name and photo correct in form data still validator gives me error. I attached screenshot –

Answer (score 0):

extend your request class with FormRequest

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class FruitRequest extends FormRequest
```

for more details visit official doc of laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#creating-form-requests